# DPI scaling runtime created controls having PopupMenu

Tags: delphi, dpi

I'm using Delphi 10.4.1 Sydney, and have created a simple control which has its `Parent` set at runtime:

```
constructor TMyTree.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(Owner);
  PopupMenu := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
end;

procedure TMyTree.ChangeScale(M, D: Integer; isDpiChange: boolean);
begin
  inherited ChangeScale(M, D, isDpiChange);
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('M: %d, D: %d', [M, D])));
  //The program is started at 150% DPI and DPI changed to 175% DPI
  //Debug Output: M: 168, D: 96 - ERROR! It should be M: 168, D: 144
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fTree := TMyTree.Create(Self);
  fTree.Parent := Self;
  OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('CurrentPPI: %d', [fTree.CurrentPPI])));
  //Debug Output at 150% DPI scale: CurrentPPI: 144 - OK!
end;
```

The problem is that `ChangeScale()` is called with wrong parameters by VCL (see the comments in the code).

I think that is caused by the fact that when `PopupMenu := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);` is called in the `TMyTree` constructor, the tree's `ComponentState` is set by VCL to `[csFreeNotification]`.

I have inspected the VCL code, more specifically `TControl.SetParent()`.  If `csFreeNotification` is in `ComponentState` then `ScaleForPPI` is *NOT* called, and our tree view is not scaled when its `Parent` is set.

Is this a bug in the VCL, or there is some other preferred way to create runtime controls and set their `Parent`?

By the way, the same issue happens if I use `TImageList.Create(Self)` in the `TMyTree` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the VCL.  There are several tickets reported in [Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com) related to it:

[RSP-15381: A scaled form gets resized to design time ClientWidth/ClientHeight when embeded in a parent form](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15381)

[RSP-18162: Frame with Assigned PopupMenu is wrong Displayed on high DPI](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18162)

[RSP-19012: Parented controls with free notifications aren't scaled](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-19012)

Comment: I have voted for these issues. Let's hope it won't take three more years to EMBA to fix them. IMHO this is a major issue.